# Jmeter : How to check json response value is null using if controller

Tags: jmeter

How to check null response value  using if controller in jmeter?

My json response looks like :
{ 
userID: null
}

Using if controller in Jmeter, I want to verify, userID is null

I am using : "${userID}"==null but this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
${__javaScript(vars.get("userID") == null)}
```

or (since Jmeter 4.0): `!${__isVarDefined(userID)}`

Answer (score 0):

What you posted doesn't look like a valid JSON to be, you can double check this using i.e. [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/) service

If your response is a valid JSON, for example it looks like:

```
{
  "userID": null
}
```

You can use the following [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) as the If Controller's condition:

```
${__groovy(new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(ctx.getPreviousResult().getResponseData()).userID==null,)}
```

[image]

More information:

- [Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [6 Tips for JMeter If Controller Usage](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage)